# Using specific version of Ruby on rails in Docker Container

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker

I am trying to build the container for the ruby on rails application. I followed the official guide provided at [official docker guide](https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/)

The problem is while creating the Gemfile I provide `gem 'rails', '~> 6.0'` but when building the docker image it overrides the rails version and installs the latest version.

I have few libraries which are not compatible with the latest version. How can I stop docker in using the latest version while building the docker container?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:3
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y nodejs
WORKDIR /backend
COPY Gemfile /backend/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /backend/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install
COPY . /backend

# Add a script to be executed every time the container starts.
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 3000

# Start the main process.
CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  mongodb:
    image: "mongo"
    volumes:
      - "mongodb:/var/lib/mongodb/data"
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: "root"
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: "root"
    ports:
      - 2717:27017
  web:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/backend
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
volumes:
  mongodb:
```

Comment: can you share your dockerfile/docker-compose?

Comment: @JuanseGimenez, I have updated the question with Dockerfile and docker-compose

Comment: hey @JuanseGimenez Thank you for your reply, I actually found the solution. the gem that I am specifying in the Gemfile should be `gem 'rails', '6.0'` instead of `gem 'rails', '~> 6.0'`

Comment: Nice, you are welcome

Answer (score 0):

`~> 6.0` is a shortcut for "`>= 6.0` and `< 7`". You need to be more specific if you don't want Rails 6.1: `~> 6.0.0`. This is equivalent to "`>= 6.0.0` and `< 6.1`".